# How to include custom data in a point data of arearange chart

Tags: highcharts

I am creating an arearange chart in Highcharts. Data to this chart is passed as an array of array like [[1,2,3],..]. Can i pass custom data in this point like [[1,2,3, "abc:12"],[5,6,7,"abc:14"]..].

If i want to pass custom data for each point, please let me know how to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keys` property to map the values and for example use the custom value in a tooltip:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        keys: ['x', 'low', 'high', 'customValue'],
        type: 'arearange',
        data: [
            [1, 2, 3, "abc:12"],
            [5, 6, 7, "abc:14"]
        ]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{point.customValue}'
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ncmy1jt7/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.arearange.keys

Or define the series data as an array of objects:

```
series: [{
    keys: ['x', 'low', 'high', 'customValue'],
    type: 'arearange',
    data: [{
        x: 1,
        low: 2,
        high: 3,
        customValue: "abc:12"
    }, {
        x: 5,
        low: 6,
        high: 7,
        customValue: "abc:14"
    }]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s035q8um/

Comment: Thanks a lot ppotaczek for giving response.